# Preparing a date for MySQL using date() and strtotime()

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have dates as text strings in the format --

```
16 October 2012
08 October 2012
04 October 2012
```

I would like to convert them into a format that is MySQL 'date' friendly.

I have the following implementation --

```
$fixed = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Which returns all dates as --

```
1969-12-31
```

Comment: seriously, if you're trying to use `strtotime()` for this, then you're in for a world of pain. The `DateTime` class makes this kind of thing trivially easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from my other answer, where I use PHP date functions to obtain the result, if you want to avoid them and use a much faster approach for your particular case, you could use the following custom function:

```
function mysql_date($d) {
    $m = array('jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec');
    $ex = explode(' ',$d);
    $mon = array_search( strtolower( substr($ex[1],0,3) ) ,$m) + 1;
    return $ex[2] . '-' . $mon . '-' . $ex[0];
}

$date='16 October 2012';
echo mysql_date($date); //echoes '2012-10-16'
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Though I do get this error when inserting into mysql `Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'date' at row 1`

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` has a list of acceptable formats, of which what you're using is not one.

You want [`strptime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)

```
$d = strptime($date, '%d %B %Y');
$fixed = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$d['tm_mon'],$d['tm_mday'],$d['tm_year']));
```

Comment: This is not working for me, date() wants a timestamp as second parameter, and you are feeding it an array.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't realize that php.net was down and you couldn't read the documentation. I've fixed the code for you and paid myself with this sarcastic remark.

Comment: Well now I get `1999-11-30` for each date.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on PHP 5.3 onwards:

```
$date='16 October 2012';
$a = date_parse_from_format($date, '%d %F %Y');
$atime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['month'], $a['day'], $a['year']);
echo date("Y-m-d", $atime);
```

If you have an older PHP version, take care your PHP is not on Windows, as `strptime()` is not implemented in windows and the recommended way is using `date_parse_from_format()` as in my above suggestion, see the warnings extracted from the [strptime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) page:

> Note: This function is not implemented on Windows platforms.
>
> Note: Internally, this function calls the strptime() function provided
> by the system's C library. This function can exhibit noticeably
> different behaviour across different operating systems. The use of
> date_parse_from_format(), which does not suffer from these issues, is
> recommended on PHP 5.3.0 and later.

So, if you have a PHP older than 5.3 and it doesn't run on windows, then you can use this code:

```
$date='16 October 2012';
$a = strptime($date, '%d %B %Y');
$atime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon'], $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year']);
echo date("Y-m-d", $atime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [`DateTime` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for this -- it makes things *so* much easier...

```
function sqlDateFromLongDate($input) {
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat($input,'d F Y');
    return $dateObj->format('Y-m-d');
}

print sqlDateFromLongDate('08 October 2012');
```

Hope that helps.

**NOTE: This solution requires PHP 5.3 and up.  (but also note that this is the minimum supported version now: if you're on a lower version, please note that php 5.2 went out of support nearly two years ago -- it's time to upgrade)